# filesystem::copy returns Invalid argument, but argument is existing fs::path variable

Tags: c++, std, file-copying, std-filesystem

I'm working with files in my project using std::filesystem (fs) library. All paths I store as fs::path variables. My code is:

```
int main(){

    std::filesystem::path root_dir = "/home/xyz/study/misis2023f-22-3-kovaleva-m-a/prj.cw/test_dir";

    std::filesystem::path from_path = "/home/xyz/study/misis2023f-22-3-kovaleva-m-a/prj.cw/test_dir/misis2023_kovaleva_m_a/make.cpp";
    std::cout << std::filesystem::exists(from_path) << '\n';

    std::filesystem::copy_file(from_path, root_dir, std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing);
}
```

I face the problem when I call fs::copy function, **Invalid argument**. But as you see, other functions (ex. fs::exists) work fine with those variables:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::filesystem::__cxx11::filesystem_error'
> what():  filesystem error: cannot copy file: Invalid argument [/home/xyz/study/misis2023f-22-3-kovaleva-m-a/prj.cw/test_dir/misis2023_kovaleva_m_a/make.cpp] [/home/xyz/study/misis2023f-22-3-kovaleva-m-a/prj.cw/test_dir]

function signature: (from cpp-reference)

```
void copy( const std::filesystem::path& from,
           const std::filesystem::path& to, 
           std::filesystem::copy_options options );
```

How can I fix this problem with argument?

I use cmake 3.22.1, ubuntu 22.04

I tried to pass argument as a string:

```
std::filesystem::copy_file("/home/xyz/study/misis2023f-22-3-kovaleva-m-a/prj.cw/test_dir/misis2023_kovaleva_m_a/make.cpp", root_dir, std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing);
```

I tried to pass shorter argument:

```
std::filesystem::path from_path = "/home/xyz/study/test_copy.txt";
std::filesystem::copy_file(from_path, root_dir, std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing);
```

I also tried to pass argument without extension:

```
std::filesystem::path from_path = "/home/xyz/study/what";
std::filesystem::copy_options::update_existing);
```

But results is the same: Invalid argument

I also tried to check **file status**:

```
std::filesystem::file_status from_path_status = std::filesystem::status(from_path);
```

Output is:

```
_M_type: std::filesystem:;file_type::regular
_M_perms: 436
```

Comment: I'm guessing the target **file name** `test_dir` already exists. Possibly as a *directory* rather than as a file.

Comment: @Eljay sorry, I didn't get, what is the problem with "test_dir"? It is a to_path, from docs: "Otherwise, if to is a directory, then behaves as if copy_file(from, to/from.filename(), options) (creates a copy of from as a file in the directory to)."

Comment: That's for `std::filesystem::copy`, not `std::filesystem::copy_file`.

Comment: I found the solution.
If I want to copy a file, an argument "to" must be a file name path, not just a directory path.
For ex, if I copy "test.cpp" from "dir1" to "dir2", the argument "to_path" should be "dir2/test.cpp"

Comment: @su-mrak if you use `fs::copy_file()`, yes. Otherwise, use `fs::copy()` instead.

Comment: I noticed that I past the wrong version of code, where I use "copy_file", and it didn't work with "copy" at the beginning. But know everything is fine.
Thank you for your help! @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to copy a file to a directory without specifying a target file name.

`std::filesystem::copy_file()` expects two *file* paths as it merely copies one file to another file. It cannot copy a file to a directory, like you are trying to do. Since you are passing it a *directory* path, it fails with the error.

You need to either

- specify a target file name for `std::filesystem::copy_file()`.
- use `std::filesystem::copy()` instead.